# Iterating through huge files and search using Regex (VB.NET)

Tags: arrays, regex, vb.net, loops, streamreader

I am creating a program that holds a List<> of item names `ItemNamelst` and I need to loop through a tremendously large file (Testing one with 173k lines, but can go bigger) and compare each line in the file to determine if an Item Name is in that line, and store the count of that specific item.

This becomes a time problem due to the length of file and number of items I am searching for (This ex. is 247 Items)

The only requirement is that I have to find when an Item occurs in the file at least 3 times, and then I "am done" searching for that item.

I'm currently holding the item occurrence counts in a 2d array, `arrItemCount(Name, Count)`

Here is some sample code:

```
While Not SR.EndOfStream
        strTemp = SR.ReadLine()
        intC1 += 1 'counter

        For i = 0 To ItemNamelst.Count() - 1
            'Loop through parts and increment count in arrItemCount
            'if part matches the regex

            Dim pattern = "(^|\W)" & ItemNamelst(i) & "($|W|:)" 'RegEx pattern

            If Regex.IsMatch(strTemp, pattern) Then
                'increment count value
                arrItemCount(0, i) = (Integer.Parse(arrItemCount(0, i)) + 1).ToString()
            End If
        Next
End While
```

If you have any links to sources about looping over large files they'd be incredibly helpful down the road

Comment: Your 2d array seems a litte bit odd. Is there a reason why you don't just use a Dictionary(Of String, Integer)  ? Because Integer.Parse and ToString every time maybe is not the fastest operation)

Comment: But there is no specific question at all (besides from "have you links?" (aka. "can you google for me?")

Comment: @Horitsu using a dictionary requires that the keys all be unique, where my key would be the Count (0 to 3 or more) so unless there’s some way to bypass that I don’t believe I can use a dictionary. The question was more of one of “Do you know of how to make this more efficient” I assumed it would be self-explanatory

Comment: If you count the occurrence of items, then you would have every key only one times. -> if your input have double items to look for, then reduce them to one and map it back afterwards. (a,a,b,c,d,e,e,f,d) -> {a,b,e,d,e,f} -> ((a,ax),(a,ax),(b,bx),(c,cx),(d,dx),(e,ex),(e,ex),(f,fx),(d,dx)). So avoid to count the exacly same key multiple times.

Comment: And get rid of this (Integer.parse(...)...).ToString(). First of all switch from a 2D-String-Array to a 1D-Tuple(Of String, Integer)-Array

Comment: And try to find alternatives for the RegEx. RegEx is very slow. 
If you can provide test samples of your raw data, someone could help you better.

Comment: @Horitsu every item should occur at least 3 times, I need to find the ones that DO NOT. I have already filtered out the items I am searching for so there are no duplicates.

Comment: Here is some sample for the RegEx                                                               `\\string must match the item EXACTLY, only characters that may come before or after are colons and singlequotes

Item To Search For: STRAP - HOSE CLAMP (9298A988541)

:STRAP - HOSE CLAMP (9298A988541): ✔ Match
'STRAP - HOSE CLAMP (9298A988541)' ✔ Match
:STRAP - HOSE CLAMP (9298A988541)-2: X Fail
`